# Moodle 3.7 - user profile custom field - custom validation

Tags: validation, moodle, profile, custom-fields

I need to add validation with regular expression against user profile custom field. Do I need to write some plugin or add additional code to moodle core ?

I am using Moodle 3.7. I have searched for it in documentation. But, Nothing found.

In my case I need to have 'mobile #' field with valid mobile number format. Mobile # format needs to be validated from regular expression I use.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is to create a new "profile field plugin" based in the existing "text" plugin (for generic text inputs) and override the validation methods to implement your custom validation.

More examples of this kind of plugin: https://moodle.org/plugins/browse.php?list=category&id=27

After your plugin is written and installed, you will be able to add your new custom field as an admin from `/user/profile/index.php`.